# Compile error with cocoa pod code in iOS 8 beta

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode6, last.fm, xcode6-beta6

I'm developing in Xcode6 Beta 6 for iOS 8.

I am encountering an code error on an imported LastFM Cocoa Pod:

[image]

when I try to compile, but I can't seem to figure out what's causing the error.  (Using all the code from the example)

I keep getting the following error in my **AppDelegate.m** file :

```
Property 'cacheDelegate' not found on object of type 'LastFm *'
```

I have however ensured to have the following code in my **LastFm.h** file :

```
 @interface LastFm : NSObject


 @property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) id <LastFmCache> cacheDelegate;
```

Any thought why it would claim I have not set the property in LastFM ?  Not sure if this is an iOS 8 issue, or simply an error on my part?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: where is a definition of the LastFMCache protocol? have you imported it if it is in other header?

Comment: Hey Julian,  I have both a LastFMCache.m and LastFMCache.h that define it.

Comment: okay but do you import .h to the right file? could you show the source code?